# regexp: how to extract substring

Tags: c#, regex

I have two strings: `"word1|word2"`, `"word2|word1"`

Is there any way with regexp to extract `word2` from these strings if it contains `word1`?

Comment: `if I only know "word1" substring` what does this mean

Comment: "word1" is a known part of the string, I want to get other part if it consist "word1"

Comment: would there only be two words separated by `|`

Answer (score 1):

`split` the string by `|` into array and then `find` any string you like to find

Comment: I'm using this approach now, I wanted to know if any regex magic can exist for this

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this would do it:

```
  var input = new String[] { "word1|word2", "word2|word1" };
  var regexp = @"word1\|(?<GROUP>.*)|(?<GROUP>.*)\|word1";
  foreach (var word in input)
  {
    var match = Regex.Match(word, regexp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["GROUP"].Value);
  }
```

But your requirements are quite unclear to me, so please feel free to ellaborate :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a more flexible approach like splitting on the "|" and checking each part, and saving the other one if you find a match.

If you really need to use regex, something like `(word1\|(.*)|(.*)\|word1)` would put word2 into backreference 1.

You may need to tweak the `(.*)` part, depending on whether this string is by itself or embedded in other text that should not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a look around...

```
 (?<=^word1\|).*|.*(?=\|word1$)
```

That way you can use

```
 match.Value
```

And disregard Groups and Captures altogether.